# Implementing Experience manager on dynamic components (Only session Preview is not working)

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t, 2013-sp1

my page have few static and dynamic component for static component presentation XPM is working fine but for dynamic Component Presentations is not correctly marked as IsRepositoryPublished == true
how i can do this.
code to use markup @Html.SiteEditPage(Model) @Html.SiteEditComponentPresentation(dynamiccomp,Model.ComponentTemplate.Id,true,‌​"region") @Html.SiteEditField(dynamiccomp,dynamiccomp.Fields["title"].EmbeddedValues[0]["l‌​inkText"])

my dynamic component are editable but update preview is not working fine 
i am using dd4t 1.31 tridion 2013 sp1

this are my PT and CT Tags.

```
<!-- Page Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:15-14635-64","PageModified":"2015-01-22T18:25:00","PageTemplateID":"tcm:15-14639-128","PageTemplateModified":"2014-12-23T05:04:01"} -->

<div> <!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "tcm:15-14789", "ComponentModified" : "2015-02-19T04:21:44", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:15-13193-32", "ComponentTemplateModified" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00", "IsRepositoryPublished" : false, "IsQueryBased" : true} --> 
 <div>  <!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:thoughtLeadershipModule/custom:title[1]/custom:linkText[1]"} -->
                            <a href="" target="" title="Most Read Piece of Relevant Dynamic">Most Read Piece of Relevant Dynamic test</a>
                         </div></div>
```

[image: dynamic CT for components]

Comment: What Templating model are you using, or what is generating the XPM markup for the published Page? If it is DD4T, can you specify a bit more detail on which version (version of Tridion, DD4T, etc.). Since then this info comes from DD4T...

Comment: we are using dd4t 1.31 Tridion 2013 sp1

Comment: dynamic component is editable but update preview is not working. when i click finish editing it published to borker successfully
 
code to use markup
@Html.SiteEditPage(Model)
 @Html.SiteEditComponentPresentation(dynamiccomp,Model.ComponentTemplate.Id,true,"region")
 @Html.SiteEditField(dynamiccomp,dynamiccomp.Fields["title"].EmbeddedValues[0]["linkText"])

Comment: could you please Edit the question and move the information from your last comment in there? That allows you to format it a lot better than in a comment making everything more readable, so you are actually going to get relevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using DD4T the fact that your update preview is not working might not have anything to do with your XPM markup actually.

For troubleshooting session preview, I suggest you check out Albert Romkes blog post http://albertromkes.com/2013/01/24/troubleshooting-the-sdl-tridion-experience-manager-with-session-preview/, here he walks you through some typical issues and supplies solutions to all of them.

As for the the Component Presentation being marked `"IsRepositoryPublished": false`, I think that is correct, since it is also marked as `"IsQueryBased" : true`.

But I would need more details about the actual Component Presentation and how it is placed on the Page to give you a complete answer on that.

Comment: my session preview is working fine for component which are placed on page but having issue when it comes dynamically using taxanomy search

Comment: @meyank what caching values are being used in DD4T? It could very well be that DD4T caching is in your way here...

Comment: i am using DD4t model i received  IComponentPresentation on view, every thing is working fine(editing of components and session preview) for components which are placed on Page but few components are coming through broker search based on schema and category attached in component displayed on view these dynamic components are editable on view using XPM but facing issues to update these components in session preview.

note: Please let me know how i can set "IsRepositoryPublished" = true